# Card game in Javascript, constructor function error

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor, this

I'm creating a basic card game (21) in JavaScript where each player has a Hand of cards. The players start out with 2 cards, but I want to add new cards depending on the total value of the cards and adjust for whether there is an ace present or not.

Unfortunately, I get this error: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. I think the problem has to to with the this.newCard method, I just can't seem to understand why it is not working.

```
function Hand () {
    this.cards = []
    this.cardsAtStart = function() {
        this.cards.push(new DealCards, new DealCards)
        return this.cards
    }
    this.checkValue = function () {
        let cardsInHand = this.cardsAtStart()

        let ace = false
        let value = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < cardsInHand.length; i++) {
            if (cardsInHand[i].cardnumber === 'A' && !ace) {
                ace = true
                value = value + 13
            }
            value = value + cardsInHand[i].cardvalue
        }
        if (ace && value  > 21) {
            value = value - 13
        }
        console.log(value)

        return value
    }
    this.newCard = function () {
        let value = this.checkValue()
        console.log(value)
        while (value < 15) {
            this.cards.push(new DealCards)
        }
        if (value > 15) {
            endGame()
        }
        console.log(this.cards)
    }
}
```

A card object looks like this: 
`{ suit: '♦', cardnumber: 'K', cardvalue: 13 }`

Comment: where is your break statement inside the while `while (value < 15) {
            this.cards.push(new DealCards)
        }`

Comment: what does your console output look like?? probably an infinite `while` loop

Comment: Are you forgetting the semicolon `;` on purpose?

Comment: yes, I think i get an infinite while loop

Comment: Out of curiosity, which browser gives such a verbose error message?

Comment: actually i'm running it in node right now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't check the value each loop:

```
this.newCard = function () {
    let value = this.checkValue()
    console.log(value)
    while (value < 15) {
        this.cards.push(new DealCards);
        // check value again here!
        value = this.checkValue()
    }
    if (value > 15) {
        endGame()
    }
    console.log(this.cards)
}
```

But also modify checkValue to move out the cardsAtStart out of there and into the constructor.

<strike>Alternatively, check the value like this:</strike>

```
while (value < 15) {
  this.cards.push(new DealCards);
  value = this.cards.reduce((all, current) => all + current.cardvalue, 0),
}
```

Scratch that, the Ace logic messes with my reducer. Stick to original plan. Move call to cardsAtStart into the constructor method. Then use checkValue to just check value.

Answer (score 2):

You will never exit the `while` loop because `value` won't change:

```
while (value < 15) {
   this.cards.push(new DealCards)
}
```

You need to change the `value` variable inside the `while` loop so the condition can be `false`.

Something like this:

```
while (value < 15) {
    this.cards.push(new DealCards);
    value++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, i guess my answer is wrong. please explain why should the OP **NOT** increase the `value` and break out of an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are stuck in an infinite loop here at this line,

```
 while (value < 15) {
     this.cards.push(new DealCards)
 }
```

The problem is the value is never larger than 15 when this function runs so it just keeps repeating.

If you want this to deal a card when the card is less than 15 then do something else you could do something like this,

```
if (value < 15) {
       this.cards.push(new DealCards)
 }
```

So to fix your problem you will need to update the value each time it loops by calling your  `this.checkValue()` function.

```
while (value < 15) {
     this.cards.push(new DealCards);
     value = this.checkValue();
 }
```

Comment: checkvalue always makes a new deck. he needs to modify that first.

Comment: Ahh yes I see what your saying. Good eye man. Good job I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This for loop will never end

```
while (value < 15) {
            this.cards.push(new DealCards)
        }
```

You will need to call value++ or ++value to make it end

```
while (value < 15) {
            this.cards.push(new DealCards);
            value++;
        }
```